# OpenPos + TeraWallet + Balance Negativo

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

espero que anden muy bien, ando con un problema que no puedo solucionar; tengo un codigo para integrar con TeraWallet en OpenPos, la cuestion es que no estoy pudiendo hacer que se registre el balance negativo en la cuenta del usuario; Registra toda la operación pero no me debita el balance de la cuenta; tengo desactivado el filtro de terawallet para las operaciones negativas. Les dejo el codigo a continuación haber si me pueden dar una ayudita. Gracias!!!

```html
<?php

if(!function_exists('op_wc_terawallet_user_data'))
{
    function op_wc_terawallet_user_data($user_data){
        $woo_wallet = $GLOBALS['woo_wallet'];

        $customer_id = $user_data['id'];

        // Show balance
        $balance = $woo_wallet->wallet->get_wallet_balance( $customer_id, 'edit');
        
        $user_data['summary_html'] = ' Balance: <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"><b>'. $balance.'</b></span>';
        return $user_data;
    }
}

add_filter('op_customer_data','op_wc_terawallet_user_data',10,1);


if(!function_exists('terawallet_op_login_format_payment_data'))
{
    function terawallet_op_login_format_payment_data($payment_method_data,$methods){
        $formatted_payment = $payment_method_data;
        $code = 'wallet';

        if( in_array($formatted_payment['code'],array($code)))
        {
            $formatted_payment['type'] = 'online';
            $formatted_payment['partial'] = 'yes';
            $formatted_payment['online_type'] = 'direct';
        }
        return $formatted_payment;
    }
}
add_filter('op_login_format_payment_data','terawallet_op_login_format_payment_data',10,2);


function terawallet_op_payment_order_payment_method($payment_method,$order_parse_data,$amount,$payment_data){
   
    foreach($payment_method as $key => $method)
    {
        if($method['code'] == 'wallet')
        {
            $_method = $method;
            $customer_id = isset($order_parse_data['customer']) && isset($order_parse_data['customer']['id']) ? $order_parse_data['customer']['id'] : 0;
            if($customer_id )
            {
                $woo_wallet = $GLOBALS['woo_wallet'];
                $balance = $woo_wallet->wallet->get_wallet_balance( $customer_id, 'edit'); 
                $order_id = $order_parse_data['order_id'];
                
                                {
                    $order = wc_get_order($order_id );
                    $wallet_response = woo_wallet()->wallet->debit( $customer_id, $amount,  'Orden: #'.$order_id , $order);
                    $_method['ref'] = $wallet_response;
                    
                }
                
                
                $payment_method[$key] = $_method;
                
            }
        }
    }
    return $payment_method;
}
add_filter('op_payment_order_payment_method','terawallet_op_payment_order_payment_method',10,4);
```

Comment: Solucionado el problema! acá dejo el codigo completo!

Answer (score 2):

Solucionado el problema, Dejo codigo!!!!!

```html
<?php

if(!function_exists('op_wc_terawallet_user_data'))
{
    function op_wc_terawallet_user_data($user_data){
        $woo_wallet = $GLOBALS['woo_wallet'];

        $customer_id = $user_data['id'];

        // Show balance
        $balance = $woo_wallet->wallet->get_wallet_balance( $customer_id, 'edit');
        
        $user_data['summary_html'] = ' Balance: <span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"><b>'. $balance.'</b></span>';
        return $user_data;
    }
}

add_filter('op_customer_data','op_wc_terawallet_user_data',10,1);


if(!function_exists('terawallet_op_login_format_payment_data'))
{
    function terawallet_op_login_format_payment_data($payment_method_data,$methods){
        $formatted_payment = $payment_method_data;
        $code = 'wallet';

        if( in_array($formatted_payment['code'],array($code)))
        {
            $formatted_payment['type'] = 'online';
            $formatted_payment['partial'] = 'yes';
            $formatted_payment['online_type'] = 'direct';
        }
        return $formatted_payment;
    }
}
add_filter('op_login_format_payment_data','terawallet_op_login_format_payment_data',10,2);


function terawallet_op_payment_order_payment_method($payment_method,$order_parse_data,$amount,$payment_data){
   
    foreach($payment_method as $key => $method)
    {
        if($method['code'] == 'wallet')
        {
            $_method = $method;
            $customer_id = isset($order_parse_data['customer']) && isset($order_parse_data['customer']['id']) ? $order_parse_data['customer']['id'] : 0;
            if($customer_id )
            {
                $woo_wallet = $GLOBALS['woo_wallet'];
                $balance = $woo_wallet->wallet->get_wallet_balance( $customer_id, 'edit'); add_filter('woo_wallet_disallow_negative_transaction', '__return_false'); 
                
                $order_id = $order_parse_data['order_id'];
                
                                {
                    $order = wc_get_order($order_id );
                    $wallet_response = woo_wallet()->wallet->debit( $customer_id, $amount,  'Orden: #'.$order_id , $order);add_filter('woo_wallet_disallow_negative_transaction', '__return_false');
                    
                    
                    $_method['ref'] = $wallet_response;
                    
                
                                }
                
                
                $payment_method[$key] = $_method;
                
            }
        }
    }
    return $payment_method;
}
add_filter('op_payment_order_payment_method','terawallet_op_payment_order_payment_method',10,4);
function terawallet_op_payment_order_result($result,$order_parse_data,$amount,$payment_data,$payment_method){
    foreach($payment_method as $key => $method)
    {
        if($method['code'] == 'wallet')
        {

            $customer_id = isset($order_parse_data['customer']) && isset($order_parse_data['customer']['id']) ? $order_parse_data['customer']['id'] : 0;
            if($customer_id )
            {
                if($method['ref'])
                {
                    $result['status'] = 1;
                }else{
                    $result['status'] = 0;
                    $result['message'] = 'No tiene saldo disponible';
                }
            }else{
                $result['status'] = 0;
                    $result['message'] = 'Please add customer to checkout with wallet';
            }
            
        }
    }
    return $result;

}
add_filter('op_payment_order_result','terawallet_op_payment_order_result',10,5);
```